# How do you calculate a success rate for a column in tbl_summary using a different column value?

Tags: r, gtsummary

My question can be conceptualized using the same sample data used for the tbl_summary trial dataset from the tutorial here: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/tbl_summary.html.

How would I calculate the mortality rate based on grade of tumor instead of calculating the incidence of grade I-III tumors? So far as I can find, there is not a way to calculate a custom statistic based on a third column, which is essentially what I am trying to do.

--- Edit ---

My input data has 3 columns - stent_type, success, stent_30. stent_type is either a category 0 or 1, success is either a 0 or 1, and stent_30 is either a 0 or 1 (basically was the stent placed before or after 30 days). I would like to create a 2x3 table with the percent/number of successfully placed stents for category 0 or 1 stents, along with a p-value comparing the two columns for stent_30. Something like this:

|  | Stent < 30 | Stent > 30 | p-value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stent 0 | 75%(10) | 70% (9) | 0.1 |
| stent 1 | 50% (6) | 40% (2) | 0.05 |

I'm basically having trouble because I'm not sure how to summarize a category based on 2 different categories (if that makes sense?)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with general tidyverse operations (`group_by` and `summarise`).

```
# Load the required libraries.

library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

# Get the mortality counts.

mortality_counts <- trial %>%
  group_by(grade, death) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup()

# Get the mortality proportions.

mortality_proportions <- mortality_counts %>%
  group_by(grade) %>%
  mutate(total = sum(count),
         proportion = count / total)
```

With the output of `mortality_proportions` as:

| grade | death | count | total | proportion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I | 0 | 35 | 68 | 0.5147059 |
| I | 1 | 33 | 68 | 0.4852941 |
| II | 0 | 32 | 68 | 0.4705882 |
| II | 1 | 36 | 68 | 0.5294118 |
| III | 0 | 21 | 64 | 0.3281250 |
| III | 1 | 43 | 64 | 0.6718750 |

If you wanted to make that clearer just to show the grade and proportions, you could do:

```
mortality_proportions %>%
  filter(death == 1) %>%
  select(grade, proportion) %>%
  mutate(proportion = round(proportion, 2))
```

For output:

| grade | proportion |
| --- | --- |
| I | 0.49 |
| II | 0.53 |
| III | 0.67 |

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have made it more clear in the initial question. This is very helpful but the comparison that I would like to make is to then compare death rates across drug A and drug B. With this approach it doesn't seem like that would be possible right?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your desired output? So a table showing what the end result should look like, even if it has fake numbers.

Comment: Okay, I think you should ask this as a new question. The original question was about data from `gtsummary` but the edit is about a different dataset and now includes p-values. I feel like it's definitely possible to achieve this, but better as a new question after reading these links: (1) https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and (2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example